# Wordpress network, add extra directory to subsite urls

Tags: multisite, url-rewriting

I'm currently developing a multisite but I can't figure out how to solve this without adding another WordPress installation.

What I want:

1. www.domain.com = main site
2. www.domain.com/events = page on the main site
3. www.domain.com/events/blabla = subsite in the network.

Any way I can accomplish this with one multisite installation?

Comment: You may need multisite , from point 1 to 3 above it seems what you trying to achieve can be achieved with custom post type and custom taxonomies.. so event will be CPT and blabla will be custom taxonomy term of events custom taxonomy

Comment: Well, point 3 really needs to be a Site in the multisite, so a CPT wouldn't really solve this? The problem I have is getting my sites in the network to point to /events/sitename/ rather then www.domain.com/sitename/. 

Point 2 wouldn't even be necessary as long as I can achieve point 3

Comment: Hmm multi site in subdirectory already complex setup, trying to move it down to directory sub level might not work out of box.

Comment: Yeah that's the problem I run into. I'd love to work with 1 multisite installation, rather than running a single installation for the main site and a network inside the /events/ folder.